# Language without free variables

Tags: lambda, functional-programming, scheme, closures, lisp

After reading the "Why the FUNARG Problem Should be Called the Environment Problem" I've asked myself a question: what happens, if we forbid defining a function, that cannot create a closure, i.e.

```
(define (foo x) (+ a x))
```

Will not be allowed at the top-level (because there is no environment to close over, containing *a*), while

```
(define (bar a) (lambda (x) (+ a x)))
```

is allowed, because returned lambda can create a closure.
Two questions here:
1. How this may affect the expressiveness of the language? Are there certain features that become unavailable with such restriction? Could someone give an example, when defining functions with free variables can be useful?
2. Does this mean that all environment variables in closures have static and predictable offsets now?

Comment: Scheme introduced lexical scoping and closures to Lisp, which effectively **solved** the “environment problem”. Modern Lisps such as Scheme/Racket, Common Lisp, and Clojure all use lexical scoping, which basically works like you describe. Emacs Lisp, however, is an interesting example of a Lisp that is still used but does not use lexical scoping by default.

Comment: You should have a look at hyper-static global environment (see e.g. http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?HyperStaticGlobalEnvironment), which is what is used if I am not mistaken in OCaml. Even redefinitions at global level shadow existing bindings and do not change the semantics of existing code, unlike in dynamic environments like Common Lisp where you can easily redefine functions.

Comment: there *is* an environment to close over - the "global" / "top level" environment. the question is, how it behaves on redefinitions of its variables -- does it mutate the bindings (i.e. it changes all the previous references to them), or shadows them (i.e. they come in effect "from now on"). The other question is, what is done in the REPL and/or in files being compiled...

Comment: @AlexisKing you cannot close over top-level environment, if it does not have the variable in it. that is the point, right?

Comment: @coredump this looks exactly like what I've meant. but there is no answer to my questions :)

Comment: Both of your functions use a free variable (or a variable bound in the top-level environment): `+‘.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said by *Will Ness* and *tfb*, there is a global environment. In your expression, both `+` and `a` are free variables. What matters is whether `a` exists or not in your global environment when you define `f`.
Besides,  "free" or "bound" is a relative notion.

There is little sense to refer to a *lexical* variable that is not bound in any environment. The only example I can think of are tied to meta-programming, but this is not really relevant because  in that case you are only manipulating code as data. When you eventually produce a form and compile or evaluate it, you still have a lexical scope and then all your symbols have to be resolved to a known variable.
With *special* variables in Common Lisp, or Emacs dynamically-scoped-by-default variables, it makes sense to refer to free variables. In Emacs you can even refer to variables which are not declared, without warnings.

> How this may affect the expressiveness of the language?

So if you disallow free variables (not bound in any lexical scope), you are basically disallowing variables with dynamic scope (in Common Lisp, they are defined has having *indefinite scope* and *dynamic extent*). You lose in expressiveness. This is the case in OCaml, for example. However, you can still define a library to simulate them, as demonstrated in [*Delimited Dynamic Binding*](http://okmij.org/ftp/Computation/dynamic-binding.html#DDBinding) and its [implementation](http://okmij.org/ftp/ML/#dynvar).

OCaml offers a [hyper-static global environment](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?HyperStaticGlobalEnvironment), which not only uses lexical scope but forbid changing existing bindings.

```
# let a = 10;;
val a : int = 10

# let f () = a;;
val f : unit -> int = <fun>

# let a = 20;;
val a : int = 20

# f ()
- : int = 10
```

Here above the second `a` shadows the previous one, but `f` still refers to the previous `a`. This is also the case for **functions**, which is why there is a `rec` keyword to define recursive and mutually recursive functions. 
This is a different approach than Lisp which is notable to allow redefining most things at runtime.

> Does this mean that all environment variables in closures have static and predictable offsets now?

Lexical scope *allows* to compile variables down to fixed locations. Whether or not this is done depends on your tools. For example, in an interpreter, your environment might be kept in a runtime data structure.